# Leaflet and R with an arctic projection

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet, wms

I'd like to use R's leaflet package outside WGS84 on the arcitc-sdi web [map tile service](http://geoportal.arctic-sdi.org/) .

I think that it might not be possible but I would like to get a definitive source. It looks like there are [plugins to do polar projections](http://webmap.arcticconnect.org/polarmap.html) with leaflet (but maybe not R's leaflet package?).

I can load "http://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/gk.open_wmts" as wms in QGIS but I can't work it with leaflet in R.

`library(leaflet);leaflet() %>% addWMSTiles("http://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/gk.open_wmts")`

Edit: I have found a similar service with a tile service like osm.

http://{s}.tiles.arcticconnect.org/osm_{projection}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

Comment: do you want to plot something on your map?

Comment: Just getting the base map working would be a great start but I would like to put geometry on top as well.

Answer (score 6):

It should work using the develop version of **mapview**.

```
    library("devtools")
    install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg/mapview", ref = "develop")
```

First you have to define the parameters of your online service. This is more ore less tricky. You will find some explanations at the `projView` [vignette](http://gisma.github.io/projView/projView1_0_9.html#some-examples).

In your case you may just use the predefined CAFF list from the example section of `projView` because it will use the CAFF sea and land surface temperatures.

You can use the list as a blueprint for further enhancements.

Then you may load an arbitrary `sp*` object you want to map. You can also use the example data set which contains the roads of Greenland.

```
    library(mapview)
    library(raster)
    load("roadsGRL")
    data("map.types")

    ### map the CAFF data
    mapview::projView(roadsGRL, map.types = map.types$CAFF)
```

[image: screenshot mapview::projView CAFF maps]

You will also find an example for the arctic connect tiles using `map.types$AC` instead.

Comment: I've having trouble compiling mapview on windows 8 and ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I just installed it on ubuntu 14.04 using `devtools::install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg/mapview", ref = "develop")` without any problems. If this problem still persists, what is the error meassage you're getting?